# ArrayLiteralConvertible only when element type is Comparable?

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm creating a sorted collection type that normally initialises from a sequence plus closure (so that I can sort elements of any type). However, I'd also like to make it `ArrayLiteralConvertible` in cases where the element type is `Comparable`, but I'm not completely sure of the best way to do this?

i.e- when the elements are `Comparable` a closure isn't required (so long as ascending order is fine).

Is it possible for a type be `ArrayLiteralConvertible` only when its element type is `Comparable`? If not, what is the best alternative (precondition failure?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
struct SortedCollection<T>: ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    init<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(_ sequence: S, isOrderedBefore: (T, T) -> Bool) {
        // ...
    }

    init(arrayLiteral elements: T...) {
        fatalError("\(T.self) is not Comparable")
    }
}

extension SortedCollection where T: Comparable {
    init<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(_ sequence: S) {
        self.init(sequence, isOrderedBefore: <)
    }

    init(arrayLiteral elements: T...) {
        self.init(elements)
    }
}

let foo = SortedCollection(arrayLiteral: 1, 2, 3)  //  Succeeds
let bar = SortedCollection(arrayLiteral: (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3))  //  Fails
```